# staging account on First Data payment integration

Tags: php, hash, firstdata

I need to integrate First Data as a payment gateway on my website. I have created test account on its staging interface : http://staging.linkpointcentral.com/.

When I submit my form I am always error 1002. 
Here's my code:

`<form method="post" action="https://www.staging.linkpointcentral.com/lpc/servlet/lppay">
<input type="hidden" name="txntype" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="timezone" value="CET"/>
<input type="hidden" name="txndatetime" value="<?php echo getDateTime() ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo createHash( "13.00","978" ) ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="storename" value="1909897411"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="fullpay"/>
<input type="text" name="chargetotal" value="13.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="978"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

function createHash($chargetotal, $currency) {
$storeId = "11111111";
$sharedSecret = "sharedsecret";
$stringToHash = $storeId . getDateTime() . $chargetotal .$currency . $sharedSecret;
$ascii = bin2hex($stringToHash);
return sha1($ascii);
}`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is createHash(); ?

Comment: @Daan I have updated the post, and included the function

Comment: Can anyone please point out where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cause of the 1002 is a mismatch between the url of your order form and the url specified in your `fdgg` connect setup. Check the name of the page; also see whether `fdgg` expects `http` or `https`.  (I hope you solved this by now, but others might need the insight!)